# The "Users" all users on a single row

Tags: bug

For some reason, the *Users* page seems to display 5 users per row, and the last one goes "out of bounds":

[image: 5 users per row on the "Users" page]

**Technical info:** Using an early 2015 Macbook running macOS 10.12.2 and Safari 10.0.2.

### Edit

I think it actually attempts to put *all* the users on the same line, not just 5, because the top 5 only are shown in my browser.

Comment: (Don't tell me that [there's no freehand circle](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43358960#43358960) :P)

Comment: I use a 2014 MacBook Pro running macOS 10.13.2 and Safari 11.0.2, and the Users page looks fine for me.

Comment: I guess it’s a Safari 10 quirk

Comment: Yes, that's what I guessed too (after checking it with my Safari 11). Not sure whether how this should be treated.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't actually specific to Quantum Computing.SE. The same happens on all SE sites in Safari 10. [Mother meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307908/337974) by [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard):

> SE switched recently to use CSS Grid Layout in the Users page, which is indeed [not supported in Safari 10](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid). (and IE 10 too)
>
> Since SE should support last two versions, I think they should revert that change and use whatever they used before to support older versions for now.